# how to solve upload limit

Tags: php, mysql, sql, apache, file-upload

Trying to import a file to phpmyadmin on vesta

Error

> No data was received to import. Either no file name was submitted, or
>   the file size exceeded the maximum size permitted by your PHP
>   configuration.

I looked at this forum, but didn't find a solution:

https://forum.vestacp.com/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=4016

Most probably dump size exceed default php limits. Try to increase post_max_size and upload_max_filesize values. I guess 64M should be enough. 
Open /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini and set

```
SELECT ALL

post_max_size = 64M

upload_max_filesize = 64M
```

Then restart the apache.

```
SELECT ALL

apachectl restart
```

If you are using CentOS or RHEL, then the php.in location is /etc/php.ini

Comment: You have answered your own question. If the max file exceeds, that means that the database file you are importing is larger than the limit. You can extend your limit in the PHP configuration (php.ini) and setting post_max_size and upload_max_filesize to what you need it to be.

In order to check if your changes have taken affect. You can create a new php file and echo phpinfo(); like so:

`<?php
echo phpinfo();
?>`

Answer (score 1):

You have answered your own question. If the max file exceeds, that means that the database file you are importing is larger than the limit.

You can extend your limit in the PHP configuration (php.ini) and setting `post_max_size` and `upload_max_filesize` to a value greater than the size of the file you are importing eg if your database file is 20MB, set it to something like 25MB. In order to check if your changes have taken affect. You can create a new php file and echo `phpinfo();` like so:

```
<?php 

echo phpinfo(); 

?>
```

Often, this can also be because of a permissions issue on your tmp directory, i suggest checking that.

Comment: Yeah but what I'm saying its not working ( php5.5)